# How can I execute Batch program on EC2 with asynchronously with send_command on SSM?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssm

I have deployed Lambda function who executes the "BATCH PROGRAM" on an EC2 by send_command of ssm.
The processing time of the "BATCH PROGRAM" is beyond the Lambda's timeout.
Thus I want run send_command with something option for ASYNCHRONOUSLY execution.
Does send_command have any execute option for switching asynchronously/synchronously?
Best Regards

Comment: I have exactly hit upon this problem now. Is there a solution?

Comment: Yes, I have fixed this by myself.The answer is very easy....
Just to call my "Batch program" via other shell script with nohup + "&".
I hope this helps you.
Regards.

Comment: @yamashken that's strange, using nohup + & doesn't seem to work for me. When it exceeds the SendCommand timeout, the command gets interrupted, and GetCommandInvocation returns an error.